# Avoid duplicate usage of timechart in one Splunk query

Tags: splunk, splunk-query, splunk-dashboard

I have a Splunk query that works fine currently.

The Splunk query is:

```
index=my-index sourcetype=my-type 
| timechart span=2h perc95(time) as m95 
| eval test1=200 
| eval test2=400 
| timechart span=2h avg(m95) as mm95, avg(test1) as "TEST_1, min(test2) as "TEST_2"
```

If I only want to use `timechart span=2h` one time in the query, but the search results should be the same. How can I modify my query?

Comment: Please spell out your logic in regards to `mm95`.   Your current code calculates average over a single value.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? What does your data look like?

Comment: Not a single value. Time is a list of different time.

Comment: @Jen  The first timechart makes one record for every two hours.  The second timechart takes those records and does something for stuff in two hour buckets - but there is only one record in every two hour bucket because of the first timechart..  To see this change `... | timechart span=2h avg(m95) as mm95 ...` to `... | timechart span=2h count, avg(m95) as mm95 ...` - the count is always 1